# Sitecore not obtaining an item's fields

Tags: presentation, components

My sitecore **Article Component** is not picking up my authors details.

I have an **Article component** that has the path to my article html page, **/Views/Basic Components/Article.cshtml**.
In my author page **Brendon Sanderson**, which is under **sitecore/content/home/Blog/**, I selected the author Brendon Sanderson from the dropdown field in the edit menu. Therefore, the dropdown field is able to pick up all the authors under **sitecore/content/Authors/**

My question is why is my **Article Component** not displaying **authorItems** fields such as **Profile Picture** or **Name**?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to sitecore stack exchange. Can you verify if your dropdown field is DropLink and not a DropList type?

Comment: HERO!!! 
It was DropList. I just changed it and it worked!

Comment: Glad to see that it worked, also added an answer so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 3):

Adding also an answer based on the comment that the field should be changed from `DropList` to `DropLink`. This is because DropList is storing the item names so the TargetItem value will be null, whereas DropLink is storing the Targeted Item's Guid and sitecore will retrieve the linked item.

You can verify the values aswell if checking the sitecore menu View -> Raw Values.